# Как в Delphi получить номер первого кластера из дескриптора файла в FAT32?

Tags: delphi, winapi, ос, системное-программирование, fat32

На вход подается директория (полный путь к файлу), на выходе получаем номер первого кластера файла в FAT32.
C помощью `hFile := CreateFile(PChar(FilePath), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);` можно получить handle (дескриптор) файла.
А как из этого дескриптора достать нужную мне информацию? В FAT32 структура дескриптора выглядит [image: следующим образом]

Мне нужно достать из него младшую (0х1A) и старшую (0х14) часть номера первого кластера.
Не представляю как мне программно в делфи это сделать.

Пробовал использовать функцию GetFileInformationByHandle, но в структуре TByHandleFileInformation есть только поля .nFileIndexHigh и .nFileIndexLow, которые возвращают какие-то слишком большие числа для текстового файла на почти пустом логическом томе.

Comment: Из хендла - почти наверняка никак. Из файловой системы надо.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32169/FDump-Dumping-File-Sectors-Directly-from-Disk-usin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Расположение файла на диске можно получить через `DeviceIoControl()` с кодом `FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS = 0x00090073`. Детали здесь: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-fsctl_get_retrieval_pointers

Драйвер вернёт вам данные через структуру `RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER` с таким содержимым, где найдёте первый кластер, и счётчик последовательной цепочки кластеров. Если файл фрагментирован, то вернётся и кол-во фрагментов с их адресами. У меня структура представлена в формате ассемблера fasm, а вы смотрите по ссылке выше:

```
struct RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER
   ExtentCount    dd  0       ;// кол-во элементов 'Extents' в массиве 
   StartingVcn    dq  0       ;// стартовый номер первой цепочки кластеров
  struct                 ;// <---- массив элементов 'Extents'
      NextVcn     dq  0       ;// кол-во кластеров в цепочке
      Lcn         dq  0       ;// номер первого кластера в данной цепочке
  ends
ends
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло. Программа выводит цепочку файлов, но если я фрагментирую файл, то он выводит цепочку ДО фрагментации, при попытке повторного нажатия хэндл файла не открывается и цепочка стирается. Проще говоря, работает с не фрагментированными файлами.

Comment: Всё должно работать, вы видимо просто не правильно оформляете вызов `DeviceIoControl()`. В поле "ExtentCount" возвращается кол-во вложенных структур, каждая из которых описывает одну цепочку кластеров, которые следуют последовательно, например от 0 до 5. Если файл фрагментирован, в поле "NextVcn" вы получите указатель на сл.непрерывную цепочку кластеров, например от 23 до 40, и т.д. Более того, в функцию нужно передавать и структуру `STARTING_VCN_INPUT_BUFFER`, со-сброшенным в нуль полем "StartingVcn".

Comment: Вроде настроил все, выводит цепочки, в основном всегда выводит на 1 кластер больше. Иногда на 2, это касается больше фрагментированных файлов . Я так понимаю это из-за вложенных структур ? Появляются какие-то лишние указатели на следующие цепочки?